# Нужна ли запятая в предложении "Может(,) и нет"?

Tags: пунктуация

Вообще, насколько я знаю, слово "может" является вводным и обособляется запятыми, ежели оно не является частью составного глагольного сказуемого и передает оттенок возможности совершения действия. Например: "Я, может, пойду в кино".
Но меня смущает усилительная частица "и" после слова "может". Подскажите, нужна ли запятая и почему.

Comment: У меня острое ощущение, что этот вопрос задавал я. Мой стиль, только я не пропускаю пробелы после знаков препинания.

Comment: Очень любопытная ситуация, Валентин!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, так как есть чёткое правило: усилительная частица от вводного слова запятой не отделяется. У Вас "и" - усилительная частица при вводном слове "может".

Comment: "И" находится не при вводном слове "может", а относится к слову "нет".

Comment: Она находится при вводном слове перед НЕТ.

Comment: То есть надо писать: "может и, нет"?

Comment: Будьте внимательны: я написала уже, что запятая не нужна. Пусть И относится к чему угодно, но она стоит рядом с "может". Нельзя дробить сочетание "может и", ибо при изъятии вводного слова получается ерунда.

Answer (score 3):

Я против трактовки И как частицы при "может". Это действительно усилительная частица, но не при "может", а при "нет". Аргументации @EkaterinaKas... до конца не понимаю. Вернее сказать, совсем не понимаю. Да, запятая не может отделять частицу от усиливаемого слова, но это никак не объясняет саму идею отнесения И к может. Сравните: "может быть, что и нет".

**Запятая же не ставится, только если вводное слово находится в начале обособленного оборота, иначе она нужна.** Нацкорпус это подтверждает, цитировать не буду, там просто море примеров.

Comment: Я тоже за запятую.

Answer (score 3):

В спорных случаях всегда нелишне познакомиться с традицией существующих написаний. В Нацкорпусе варианты с запятой являются преобладающими, включая классиков, например:

Эти чиновники ― Бог весть: может, и да, а может, и нет.

"Может, это и хорошо. А может, и нет".

"Есть ли, например, у этой темы  особенная, иносказательная миссия? Быть может, и нет".

"Может, и в самом деле государь Петр Федорович есть, а может, и нет".

"Может, простит, а может, и нет".

Здесь две синтаксические конструкции: вводная часть " может/а может" и основная часть "и нет", в которой частица "И" усиливает значение слова, перед которым стоит, выделяя и подчеркивая его.

Написания без запятой возможны в тех случаях, когда в предыдущей части "может" является сказуемым:

Да, это может случиться, а может и нет (=может не случиться)

Он (Высший разум) может быть, а может и нет (=может не быть)

Answer (score 2):

Мне все-таки кажется, что запятая здесь необходима. Попробую обосновать свою точку зрения.

Заменим исходное предложение на немногим более информативное, например: "Может, и сделает". Если мы оставим запятую в покое, слово "может" будет восприниматься как вводное, а сообщение — как имеющее своей целью выразить сомнение в том, что обсуждаемое лицо не станет производителем некоторого действия.
Теперь избавимся от запятой — и получим предложение, осложненное однородными сказуемыми, цель сообщения которого — поведать о том, что некто обладает способностью совершить некоторое действие и совершит его.

Существенная разница, не так ли?

Не вижу причин, по которым  мы не можем распространить выводы, полученные из наблюдения над зависимостью семантики данного предложения от пунктуационного оформления, на всю совокупность случаев непосредственного следования частицы "и" за словом "может".

Answer (score 1):

[[@EkaterinaKas](/users/997/ekaterinakashtanova4)](/users/997/ekaterinakashtanova4)..., не могли бы Вы дать ссылку на такое правило. Что-то не нахожу...

Спасибо, интересная статья (подробная классификация вводных слов). Но вынуждена с Вами не согласиться. Если бы было так: "И может, нет" или: "А может, нет", именно тогда частица "и" или "а" не относилась бы к вводному слову и между ними не ставилась бы запятая. Но запятая должна обязательно отделить вводное слово от предложения:

После этого, по сути, и спрашивать об её отношениях к Григорию было незачем.

(Частица "и" относится к предложению.)

Чего доброго, пожалуй, и женится.

Так же и в предл. "Может, и нет" частица "и" относится к предложению, а не к вводному слову.

Единственное, когда отсутствие запятой было бы оправдано:
"Он может это сделать. А может и нет."
То есть только в том случае, если "может" будет членом предложения.

Comment: Это справочник по русскому языку, цитата: "Усилительные частицы при вводных словах не отделяются от них запятой: Уж вероятно, это так, поскольку нет никаких противопоказаний."  
 Нашла здесь:http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html

Comment: Практически со всем согласна, кроме предложения "Может и нет". Не относится И к слову НЕТ. Другой пример: Может И приду. Здесь вводное слово МОЖЕТ употреблено с усилительной частицей И. Именно эти случаи имеются в виду, когда усилительная частица относится к вводному слову, а не к предложению. Именно тогда не ставится запятая.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать вводное слово из предложения. Что получится? Вот почему запятая в таких предложениях не ставится. А в тех предложениях, что Вы привели в ответе, убрать вводное слово можно без проблем. Но такие предложения и не вызывают вопросов.

Comment: Пожалуй, с Вами можно согласиться. Но то, что частица "и" находится в постпозиции по отношению к вводному слову "может", довольно необычно. В таком случае "может" все же остается вводным словом в нашем случае? Если да, то это очень "исключительное" исключение (когда слово является вводным и не отделяется запятой).