# Выделение запятыми слова "может"

Tags: пунктуация

**Я (,)может(,) и ошибаюсь, но иногда бывают такие предчувствия.**

Answer (score 2):

Да, запятые нужны, "может" вставное слово, так как:
 - высказывание субъективное (автор подчеркивает, что это его личное мнение);
 - присутствует тон неуверенности;
 - "может" не является членом предложения, а вносит дополнительную информацию.

Возможно, со мной не согласятся, так как здесь есть частица "и". Подобный вопрос обсуждали [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82). Но, честно говоря, не вижу причин не выделять запятыми слово "может" в данном случае.

Answer (score 1):

Может = может быть. Это вводное слово, которое выделяется запятыми

Answer (score 1):

Екатерина, мне кажется, Вы все же ошибаетесь. В  формулировке, на которую Вы ссылаетесь, имеется в виду именно то, о чем говорится: усилительная частица **не отделяется!**  Там не говорится о том, что вводное слово не выделяется. И в пример приводится везде один и тот же: **Уж вероятно,** это так, поскольку нет никаких противопоказаний. (Частица не отделяется, а вводное-то выделено!). Нашла еще один пример, снова с частицей *уж* в пособии для поступающих Борисоглебской:
*"Примечание. Усилительные частицы при вводных словах запятой от них не отделяются: Я князя Коко знаю мало и**, уж конечно,** предпочитаю беседу с вами."* Частица НЕ отделяется, но вводное выделено вместе с частицей. 
К сожалению, примеров с другими словами не нашла. 
Я считаю, запятые нужны. Если считать И усилительной частицей и последовать правилу, получится ерунда:   Я, может и(,) ошибаюсь
Я согласна с Виктором и Инной и расставляю знаки так же.  ***Я, может, и  ошибаюсь...***
Кстати, почему ни У РОзенталя, ни у Лопатина о таком случае ничего не говорится?

**Добавляю**. Усилительная частица И употребляется перед словом, значение которого она усиливает. Вот здесь посмотрите. [Виноградов о частице](http://www.slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5310&0a0=20)

Comment: Да, я, конечно, помню и этот пример (уж конечно), и формулировку правила. Там запятая стоит после КОНЕЧНО, и это правильно, ведь частица УЖ стоит ПЕРЕД ним. У нас другой пример. Не нужны тут запятые, я уверена (пока). Сравните: Может, я и ошибаюсь. Тут ведь без проблем! Между вводным словом и частицей стоит подлежащее, запятая нужна. Но надо найти всё-таки доказательства моей или Вашей правоты. Времени бы только побольше в сутках...

Comment: Я одного не пойму. Почему вы считаете, что И - усилительная частица при "может", а не при "ошибаюсь", например?

И, частица.  
~1.  
Усиливает значение слова, перед которым стоит, для выделения, подчёркивания его. И какая же ты стала слезливая.  
~2.  
Соответствует по зн. частицам: тоже, также. * Будет и на нашей улице праздник (Погов.). Все говорят: нет правды на земле. Но правды нет - и выше (Пушкин).  
~3.  
Соответствует по зн. частице даже. Отец и не подозревал о переживаниях сына... 
Любой случай подходит, но частица всегда *перед* усиливаемым словом.

Comment: А в предложении "Да ладно уж, что с вами делать..."???

Comment: Екатерина, считаете ли Вы, что "может" в данном случае является вводным словом, несмотря на отсутствие запятых?

Answer (score 1):

Нужны, может - вводное слово.

Answer (score 1):

Свободная квантовая частица может находиться в состоянии со строго определённым волновым вектором.

Свободная квантовая частица, может, находится в состоянии со строго определённым волновым вектором.