# Запятая при "может быть"

Tags: вводные-слова

*Может быть(,) и так. А(,) может быть(,) и не так.* Нужно ли обособлять **может быть** в этих предложениях?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что касается первого предложения, возможны два варианта:

> *Говорит ― шла в город на работу и остановилась, чтобы отдохнуть. ― Что же, **может быть и так,** ― согласился Курцер* [Ю. О. Домбровский. Обезьяна приходит за своим черепом, часть 2 (1943-1958)].
>
> *Своей, мол, природы у евреев нет, а к чужой они равнодушны. Что ж, **может быть, и так*** [Сергей Довлатов. Заповедник (1983)].

В первом случае это ***член предложения**,* во втором — ***вводное слово**.* В примерах грань еле уловимая. Например, в первом оно могло бы быть и вводным.

Разница в том, что, если "может быть" вводное, оно воспринимается как единое целое, от него нельзя задать вопрос к другим словам. А если это член предложения, тогда ***вопрос задать можно*** (может быть как? так) и чувствуется ***действие по глаголам**.* Кроме того, вопрос можно задать и от одной части сочетания к другой (может что делать? быть).

А вообще, я считаю, что если делать "может быть" здесь вводным, то лучше ***пояснить слово "так"**.* Например *"может быть, и так он справится".*

Во втором предложении те же два варианта. Только в том случае, если "может быть" вводное слово, запятая перед ним не нужна, поскольку при изъятии его фраза становится бессмысленной.

О стыке союза с вводным словом говорится [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach2) (пункт 3):

> Вводные слова и сочетания могут отделяться или не отделяться запятой от предшествующего сочинительного союза в зависимости от контекста.
>
> Запятая после союза **ставится**, если вводное слово можно опустить или переставить в другое место предложения без нарушения его структуры.
>
> ...Если же изъятие вводного слова невозможно (т. е. союз включается во вводную конструкцию, образуя с ней единое сочетание), то запятая после союза не ставится (обычно это бывает при союзе *а*).

И там же пример, похожий на ваш, из песни Вертинского:

> *Вы, кажется, потом любили португальца,
>
> **А может быть,** с малайцем вы ушли.*

Comment: Спасибо. Мне кажется, что в первом предложении это всё же член предложения. Я склонялась к отсутствию запятых, но во втором засомневалась. Смотрела здесь: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/6127/%d0%9d%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%9c%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%82, но так и не определилась. Думала, что если бы это было не "может быть", а просто "может" -- запятую поставила бы.

Comment: Ориентируйтесь на то, какой смысл хотите вложить: действие по глаголу "может" или вставку, от которой нельзя никаких вопросов задать.