# А может быть — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация

> Кстати, подумай заранее, что тебе больше нравится — художественное, документальное кино или анимационное, а может быть вообще видеоблог.

У автора такая пунктуация.

Я бы поставила двоеточие вместо тире и запятую после "а может быть". Также, мне кажется, слово "кино" лучше написать после слова "анимационное". Вопросительный знак нужен или нет?

Как правильно/лучше?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/457524/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: То, где "кино" стоит, очень соответствует разговорной речи, раздумчивости. Особенно если это кто-то так сказал, лучше не нарушать стиля этого человека.

Comment: Кстати, подумай заранее, что тебе больше нравится: художественное, документальное кино или анимационное, а может быть, вообще видеоблог? ВОТ ТАКАЯ ПУНКТУАЦИЯ - ПРАВИЛЬНАЯ? ЕЩЁ НЕ УВЕРЕНА, НУЖЕН ЛИ ЗДЕСЬ ВОПРОСИТЕЛЬНЫЙ ЗНАК.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможны **два варианта оформления** (с присоединительным тире и двоеточием).

(1) *Кстати, подумай заранее, **чтО** тебе больше нравится — художественное, документальное или анимационное кино, а может быть, вообще видеоблог?*

(2) *Кстати, подумай заранее, что тебе больше **нрАвится:** художественное, документальное или анимационное кино, а может быть, вообще видеоблог?*

**Пояснение**

1. Выбор тире или двоеточия связан с разной постановкой **логических ударений** (ударная позиция слова обозначена в тексте).
2. При постановке двоеточия делается интонационное предупреждение (неполное понижение тона перед значительно увеличенной паузой). При постановке присоединительного тире полное понижение тона, а пауза короче.
3. **Союз А** относится к вводному слову и обособляется вместе с ним.
4. Вопросительный знак ставится, так как в придаточной части содержится вопрос (есть вопросительное слово ***что***).

**Приложение** (о вопросительном знаке)

**Розенталь (пункт 4)** http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

4. Вопросительный знак **ставится** в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если вопрос содержится и в главной, и в придаточной частях предложения или только в главной части, либо в придаточной: Вы знаете, что такое сестры милосердия? (Остр.); Всякого рода нарушения, уклонения, отступления от правил приводили его в уныние, хотя, казалось бы, какое ему дело? (Ч.)

Примечание. Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения содержит **косвенный вопрос,** то в конце предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится: Я прервал речь Савельича вопросом, сколько у меня всего денег (П.); Корчагин неоднократно спрашивал меня, когда он может выписаться (Н. О.).

Однако, если косвенный вопрос содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, в конце сложноподчиненного предложения ставится вопросительный знак: Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за огни? (Л. Т.); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (М. Г.)

Comment: Спасибо! Читаю Вас - и глоток свежего воздуха! Это не лесть!

Comment: Спасибо! И я правда старалась дать вам полный ответ, так как чувствую ваш интерес к языку.